# Finding all expressions of a number as an exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation

Is there a way to systematically determine all the ways a number can be expressed as an exponentiation of two natural numbers? For example,

```
64 = 64^1 = 8^2 = 4^3 = 2^6
```

, but how would I determine this without brute-forcing through roots or logarithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are allowed to factorise the number, you would find the prime factorisation, and the highest common factor $d$ of all the exponents - any factor of $d$ works.

So in your example you get $2^6$.

$6=2^1\times 3^1$ and there will be $(1+1)\times (1+1)=4$ possibilities

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing the number of possibilities can be generalized as: For a largest common factor that itself has a prime factorization of `p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pn^en` there are `(p1+1) * (p2+1) * ... * (pn+1)` ways to arrange those factors on the inner or outer exponent?

Comment: @Tobl you probably mean $(e_1+1)\dots$ for the factorisation of the $d$ I mention.

Comment: yes, right, those should all be `ei`, not `pi`. I don't think comments can be edited?

Comment: @Tobl If what I said is helpful, that is enough

Answer (score 5):

"Brute-forcing through roots" is actually a fine strategy, though... you only need to check $a^{1/n}$ for $O(\log a)$ possible exponents $n$.

Of course there are complications involved in numerically extracting the $n$th root; these can be avoided by doing a binary search on integers $b$ to find a $b$ which minimizes $|b^n - a|$. This version of the algorithm will run in $O(\log a)^2$ time (since you will need $O(\log a)$ iterations of binary search).

Finally, you can of course factor $a$ and look at the prime exponents in the factorization. In terms of algorithmic complexity, this will be *slower* than the "brute force" solution, since there is no known factorization algorithm that runs in time polynomial in $\log a$.